# Why does my "add to cart" button not work?

Tags: php, html, e-commerce

My website uses a private e-commerce system, and unfortunately, while their support team are very helpful, they are not particularly supportive of 'custom code', such the code that I require.

I am trying to configure a "splash" page (which pops up before users complete their order), which offers users the opportunity to buy one of our t-shirts half-price, with an "add to cart" allowing them to add it to their cart from within the splash page.

I have tried copying code from the standard product pages, but unfortunately the button does not work as it should, and instead it simply links through to '#' (which can be seen in the code below).

```
<form action="includes/cart/add_to_cart.inc.php" method="get" name="addcartform" id="addcartform" onsubmit="return false;">   
<!-- Important hidden inputs -->
<input type="hidden" id="js" name="js" value="false" />
<input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="{product:id}" />
<a id="add_to_cart" style="display:none;" href="#" onclick="{product:add_to_cart_js}" class="generated_button" title="Add To Cart" >
<img src="images/icons/cart_add.png" align="absmiddle" />
<span> Add To Cart </span> </a>
<noscript>
<!-- non javascript -->
<input class="generated_button"  type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name="submit" id="cart_submit" />
</noscript>
```

After putting the code in, I change the "display" of the link to "inline-block" (so that it shows), and I also tried putting in the ID of the product that I want users to add to their cart here:

```
id="product_id" name="product_id" value="{product:id}"
```

Unfortunately none of this has worked, and as I dont have complete (or easy) access to all of the files I need, I'd really appreciate any help with getting this one resolved!

Thanks in advance,
Dan

**UPDATE:** The support team behind our eCommerce system have since sent me this piece of code to help, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it:

> If you want more control via javascript you can use the core Cart object we make available > in the javascript. Its accessable via the (Private eCommerce System) namespace, and in
>   fact if you open up the console in an (Private eCommerce System) site and type in (Private > eCommerce System) and hit enter it will return an object to you of what parts of the core > system we make available to you right in the javascript so far, (this will increase in
>   time too).
>   The (Private eCommerce System).Cart object has a sub addItem() method/function that can be used here.
>
> You can pass it the product id to add it to cart: (e.g. adding a product with id #52)
>       Cart.addItem(52);
>   Or you can pass it these full options like so:

```
Cart.addItem({
productId: 52,
qty: 1,
options: {},
wishlistId: 0,
extraData: "Some detail i want to show to the user"
}, function () {
console.log('This is the callback for when its complete!');
});
```

> So if they add a button or link, they can use jQuery to set on click of that button to run that code, e.g.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('.some-button').on('click', function () {
    Cart.addItem(52);
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: What are you expecting the onclick to do? As far as I can see is you are saying on click javascript object.  Which to me makes no sense.  You need to fire a function on click which then does something.

Comment: Looks like template code

Comment: Hi Jon and Dale, thanks for your help. Sorry for not being clearer :) I'm hoping the button will add a particular product to the users cart before they complete their order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you swap out the Javascript button and replace it with the no-script input field?

```
<form action="includes/cart/add_to_cart.inc.php" method="get" name="addcartform" id="addcartform" onsubmit="return false;">   
<!-- Important hidden inputs -->
<input type="hidden" id="js" name="js" value="false" />
<input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="{product:id}" />
<input class="generated_button"  type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name="submit" id="cart_submit" />
<img src="images/icons/cart_add.png" align="absmiddle" />
<span> Add To Cart </span>
</form>
```

You might need to re-style the form fields and the `<span>` which says "Add to Cart" to get it looking right...

**UPDATE:**

Given the information the support team have provided, try putting this in your "splash page", instead of the form above.

```
<div>
<script>
function addTshirtToCart(){
    /* Swap out the 34 for the actual product ID of the tshirt you want to
       add to the basket */
    Cart.addItem(34);
    // You might also want some code here to close the "splash page"
    return false;
}
</script>
<a href="#" id="add_to_cart" onclick="return addTshirtToCart();">
    <img src="images/icons/cart_add.png" align="absmiddle" />
    <span> Add To Cart </span>
</a>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Replace the existing `div` from my 2nd answer and replaced it with this which works for me:

```
<form action="includes/cart/add_to_cart.inc.php" method="get" name="addcartform" id="addcartform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="hidden" id="js" name="js" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="1618">

    <a id="add_to_cart" style="" href="#" onclick="update_cart_content(); return false;" class="generated_button" title="Add To Cart">
    <img src="images/icons/cart_add.png" align="absmiddle">
    <span> Add To Cart </span> </a>
    <noscript>
        <input class="generated_button" type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name="submit" id="cart_submit"/>
    </noscript>
</form>
```

**UPDATE 3**

To close the popup when adding the t-shirt to the cart, try putting this in the `a` element above:

```
onclick="update_cart_content(); spashBox.close(); return false;"
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your input, it's much appreciated. Unfortunately, that code has a </a> tag, but there isn't an opening tag, and as such the button is not working correctly. Could you advise how to alter it (ie: where/if the opening <a> needs adding)

Comment: @Dan sorry, I've removed that closing `</a>` tag now - it wasn't needed.

Comment: Hi Jon, unfortunately it didn't :( Thanks for taking the time though, I really appreciate it.
I've just received a little bit of the help from the support team, but I'm not entirely sure what to do with it to be honest, I'll post the message in a main reply.

Comment: @Dan I've updated my answer to incorporate the extra information you posted

Comment: Many thanks, unfortunately it's still just linking me through to splash_page# (adding the hash after it is clicked). If it helps, here is a link to my splash page - http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/splash_page#
Many thanks for all your help so far Jon

Comment: @Dan yes that was very helpful to visit the link - try out my 2nd update, I've just tested it by using Chrome Dev Tools (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) and it worked for me!

Comment: That worked a treat! Thank you so much for the time and help Jon, I really appreciate the support and patience, as I'm very much a front-end designer, and very new to development.

Comment: Sorry to request more help, but is there a way of shutting the splash popup when the user clicks the add to cart button? At the moment, the cart pops up under the splash page, and ideally the splash page would close.

Comment: @Dan can you provide the code showing how the splash page pops up?

Comment: Unfortunately because it's on a private eCommerce platform, much of the code is "hidden" so-to-speak. If you go through to the checkout at pinknoise-systems.co.uk it should pop up for you. Hopefully that'll help!

Comment: @Dan Have a look at the 3rd update to my answer. Hopefully that'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately it doesn't close the popup. I've put the code in place on the splash page though if that's helpful for you to take a look at. Thanks again for all your help

Comment: @Dan Sorry, change it from `splashBox.close()` to `spashBox.close()`

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks so much for all your help, and a fantastic solution. 10/10! :)